# Keeping values in XSLTForms wizard (multi step forms)

Tags: xforms, xsltforms

I'm building a wizard with the XSLTForms implementation of XForms, and I'm having a trouble with multi-step forms. When I complete data in form1 and navigate to form2, all the data entered in form1 disappears. In order to navigate, I use a trigger

```
<xf:trigger>
    <xf:label>Next</xf:label>
    <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
        <xf:load show="replace">
            <xf:resource value="form2.xml"/>
        </xf:load>
    </xf:action>
</xf:trigger>
```

I suppose the problem is I am not saving the model, so I added a submission to my model:

```
<xf:submission id="saveData" resource="data.xml" ref="instance('person')" method="put" validate="false" relevant="false" replace="none" />
```

So I replaced the "Next" trigger with a submit:

```
<xf:submit submission="saveData">
    <xf:label>Next</xf:label>
    <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
        <xf:load show="replace">
            <xf:resource value="form2.xml"/>
        </xf:load>
    </xf:action>
</xf:submit>
```

But still have a problem: the navigator asks the user for permission to write the file, and I really want to do that at the end, not in every form.

Is there any alternative to this? Thanks a lot!

Here an example for better understanding:

```
<xf:instance xmlns="">
    <person>
        <name/>                     <!--Form 01-->
        <surname/>                  <!--Form 01-->
        <height/>                   <!--Form 01-->
        <weight/>                   <!--Form 01-->
        <children>
            <age/>                  <!--Form 02-->
            <school-name/>          <!--Form 02-->
        </children>
        <has-car/>                  <!--Form 03-->
        <wanna-share-car/>          <!--Form 03-->
    </person>
</xf:instance>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XForms can be used for designing a single page application.

With XForms 1.1, all the application is written into a single form. Cases can be used to display, step by step, the controls. Relevant MIP can also be used for that.

XForms implementations such as betterForm and XSLTForms have added a subform mechanism allowing parts of a form to be loaded/unloaded. Unfortunately, this has not been included in XForms 2.0 proposed recommendation so this is a non-standard mechanism.

Subforms in XSLTForms are very versatile: they can shared the same models and instances, they can also have their owns. No specific actions or functions are required with XSLTForms.

--Alain

Comment: Hi Alain! What you made in XSLTForms is what I really need. It's a shame they didn't considered to XForms. The problem is, when I use the first method mentioned in my post (just a trigger with a load), I complete the form1, navigate to the form2, and then I access the model from JS, but it returns the model without the previously entered values. I'm accessing with this:

var model = window.document.getElementById("model1");
var inst = model.getInstanceDocument("person");
var sXML = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(inst);
console.log(sXML);

Comment: Even if I just complete the form2 data and navigate again to form1 (with another trigger with a load action) the form is empty, and the previously entered information is lost.

Comment: I'm using the same file for instance data, like this way:
<xf:model id="model1"> <xf:instance id="person" resource="model1.xml"/> </xf:model>